# FQL filtering by user_id and url in url_like

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to know if a user liked a URL. I followed the facebook documentation in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like. I had no problem to get all likes by user_id using the query bellow:

select user_id, url from url_like where user_id=me()

The result of this FQL is a list of URLs liked by the user. The problem occours when i add to WHERE clause the URL parameter like this:

select user_id, url from url_like where user_id=me()and url='http://www.climatempo.com.br/previsao-do-tempo/cidade/321/riodejaneiro'

the result is an empty list, but the result appears in the first list.

Any idea?

P.S I tested using graph api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to fetch. As the url_like table contains only two columns and if you query using both columns in where clause, it does not make any sense.